# Send reminder email one day before Event Started

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying find out how to send a reminder email to users one day before Event started lets say for example: 
There is an event which is going to start: 03-02-2020
and 
I want send reminder one day before: 02-02-2020

Her is my query :

```
  var RegistrtionToEvent = db.Registrations
                .Where(t => (t.LastNotifiedDate == null) && t.Status == "signedup" &&
                 t.EventStartDate //here is my problem what it should be done here with EventStartDate)
                .ToList();

            if (RegistrtionToEvent != null && RegistrtionToEvent.Any())
            {
                foreach (var item in RegistrtionToEvent)
                {

                        item.LastNotifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                        //sending Email

                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Can anyone please help me! :)

Thanks

Comment: Define a `DateTime startsOn` variable before the query and then use it in the `Where` statement. Example: `t.EventStartDate == startsOn`

Comment: Can you do t.EventStartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) (you might need to play around to strip out the time if this is not important)

Comment: @Igor i think i get you bad example , but lets say there is an event which is start : 03-02-2020 and it should send email 02-02-2020

Comment: So change the name `startsOn` to whatever you want like `notifiyOn` and then assign it that value instead.

Comment: @Igor it dosent matter variable name , i just want to find out the condtion one day before event started

Comment: Just updated the ans, let me know if that helps @TheProfessorandtheMadman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standalone example:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime notify = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
if(notify.Day == now.Day + 1)
    Console.WriteLine(" You are notified since you have an event tomorrow: " + notify.Day);
```

Or

```
var RegistrtionToEvent = db.Registrations
                    .Where(t => (t.LastNotifiedDate == null) && t.Status == "signedup" &&
                     notify.Day == now.Day + 1).ToList();
```

In your example (*Assuming that `EventStartDate` is of type DateTime*):

```
DateTime notify = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
var RegistrtionToEvent = db.Registrations
                    .Where(t => (t.LastNotifiedDate == null) && t.Status == "signedup" &&
                     notify.Day == t.EventStartDate.Day).ToList();
```

Just access the `.Day` attribute of your `EventStartDate` and compare that to tomorrow.

*What happens here?*

We check if tomorrow is the event-day. Essentially `Today + 1 == EventStartDate`

Comment: thanks @joel for help and +1 for this line We check if tomorrow is the event-day. Essentially Today + 1 == EventStartDate :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
var dt = DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(1);


var RegistrtionToEvent = db.Registrations
                .Where(t => (t.LastNotifiedDate >= dt && t.LastNotifiedDate <= dt) && t.Status == "signedup"
                 //&& t.EventStartDate //here is my problem what it should be done here with EventStartDate
                 )               
                .ToList();
```